# UPDATE SET column with different values per row

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table `my_table` like this:

```
| id | val1 | val2|
| 1  | foo1 | bar |
| 2  | foo2 | baz |
| 3  | foo3 | bam |
```

And I have a hard-coded comma-separated list of values that I have generated programmatically: `spam, eggs, ham`.

I want to insert my values into the column `val1`. I am imagining something like this:

`UPDATE my_table SET val1 = SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('spam'),('eggs'),('ham'))`

But this gives me a syntax error (MySQL 5.6.44)

Final result should look like this:

```
| id | val1 | val2|
| 1  | spam | bar |
| 2  | eggs | baz |
| 3  | ham  | bam |
```

Comment: You can't do that.  You can either update all rows, or you can tell it specific rows to update (`update my_table set val1 = 'spam' where id = 1`)

Comment: Do you want each row in your table to have all three values?

Comment: You need to update the separate  values in each value in val1 by the seperated value. My question is you need the any of the value can update in val1 or it has an order to update in val1?

Comment: I'm assuming he meant row1 should get 'spam', row2 'eggs' and row3 'ham' ?

Comment: I guess you would need to create a temporary table and `UPDATE ... JOIN` to do this, or run X separate `UPDATE` queries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*@Strawberry*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58014470/2469308) is exemplary indeed; but what if the `id` values are non-continuous.

For instance, the `id` values are `2, 5, 6`. In this case, we can emulate a continuous `new_id` using [`Row_Number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) functionality in MariaDB 10.2+ / MySQL 8+. I also noticed that your input comma-separated string is having spaces after comma. To handle that (variable amount of spacing), we can use [`Trim()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function after the substring operation. Building upon [excellent answer by *@Strawberry*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58014470/2469308):

**Schema (MySQL v8.0) - [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hphCvCasoqqGdrrXhamkoM/2)**

```
CREATE TABLE your_table_name
(id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
,val1 VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,val2 VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO your_table_name VALUES
(2,'foo1','bar'),
(5,'foo2','baz'),
(6,'foo3','bam');
```

---

**Update Query**

```
UPDATE your_table_name t1
       JOIN (SELECT Row_number()
                      OVER (
                        ORDER BY id) AS new_id,
                    id
             FROM   your_table_name) t2
         ON t2.id = t1.id
SET    val1 =
Trim(Substring_index(Substring_index('spam, eggs,  ham', ',', t2.new_id), ',', -1));
```

---

**Check Data**

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name;

| id  | val1 | val2 |
| --- | ---- | ---- |
| 2   | spam | bar  |
| 5   | eggs | baz  |
| 6   | ham  | bam  |
```

### ---

In older versions of MySQL/MariaDB, the window functions are not available. In that case, we can utilize [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) to emulate `new_id`:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7) - [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hphCvCasoqqGdrrXhamkoM/3)**

```
CREATE TABLE your_table_name
(id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
,val1 VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,val2 VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO your_table_name VALUES
(2,'foo1','bar'),
(5,'foo2','baz'),
(6,'foo3','bam');
```

---

**Update Query**

```
UPDATE your_table_name t1
       JOIN (SELECT @rn := @rn + 1 AS new_id, 
                    id 
             FROM   your_table_name 
             CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) vars
             ORDER BY id) t2
         ON t2.id = t1.id
SET    val1 =
Trim(Substring_index(Substring_index('spam, eggs,  ham', ',', t2.new_id), ',', -1));
```

---

**Check Data**

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name;

| id  | val1 | val2 |
| --- | ---- | ---- |
| 2   | spam | bar  |
| 5   | eggs | baz  |
| 6   | ham  | bam  |
```

Answer (score 6):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,val1 VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,val2 VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'foo1','bar'),
(2,'foo2','baz'),
(3,'foo3','bam');

UPDATE my_table SET val1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('spam,eggs,ham',',',id),',',-1);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------+------+
| id | val1 | val2 |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | spam | bar  |
|  2 | eggs | baz  |
|  3 | ham  | bam  |
+----+------+------+
```